# EE API to get Entries outside of the EE environment

Tags: api, open-api

i want to build an APP which need access to channels of my EE instance. I found Open API (https://github.com/putyourlightson/open-api) but it is outdated (last change > 5 yrs). Is there another way to get the entries (and other stuff maybe) or has someone experience with using Open API with EE?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the excellent https://addons.reinos.nl/webservice

Comment: Mhm.. i will take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can get Channel Entries by using latest feature of EE and i.e.`Model`. You need to write below code to get the entries.

```
$data = ee('Model')->get('ChannelEntry')
    ->filter('channel_id', 'enter_your_channel_id') //filter by channel_id
    ->all();
```

Here, I have included only `channel_id` as a `filter` parameter but you can add many more according to your requirement.

Comment: I can use these php code in a ee template which can be used api?

Comment: Yes, this PHP code will works in EE templates with turning on PHP. In other way, you can create simple plugin from where you can return `$data` by parsing the template variable.

Comment: is there somewhere a documentation about ee('Model') and other php classes? In the official docs i doesn't find smth

Comment: @Lars There is no official docs for EE Models. You can get more idea by reviewing it's core files.